# Finding Magnitude & Direction

Tags: vectors

As observed from a vessel moving due south at 12knots, the wind appears to blow from the east.
After the vessel has changed course, and as it is moving due west at 12 knots, the wind appears to blow from the northeast. 
Assume that the true wind velocity is constant during the period of observation.

Determine the magnitude and direction of the true wind velocity by using mathematical method.

Comment: What mathematical methods have you used? What have you tried? Where did you get this problem from? Where are you stuck on? Show some context - no one's going to help until you spend some effort into answering your own question.

Comment: well, got this as a end of term class quiz.
i tried using trigonometric functions and algebra. No progress from there.
if no one can solve then too bad.. i just have to wait till next term start and wait for the answer to the quiz .

Answer (score 0):

let the velocity of wind be $v_w=x\hat{i} +y\hat{j}$ and velocity of vessel be $v_v$.i here represents the horizontal direction and j represents the vertical direction.

now $v_{wv}=v_w-v_v$.

In the first case,as the wind seems to point in the east direction meaning $v_{wv}$,only has i component, then the j component must be zero.so y=-12.

similarly from the second case,x=-24 as $v_{wv}=-k\hat{i}-k\hat{j}$